# Scraping web data using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, data-science

I am trying to download data from the Bureau of Transportation Statistics using Python and Selenium.

The volume of the data is high, so I would only like to select specific fields. I am selecting each checkbox by title. This seems to work well, except for OriginAirportID. Instead of those, OriginAirportSeqID and  OriginCityMarketID is selected. Similar for DestAirportID. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

```
def download_data(selected_vars=None):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() #create a new profile
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    #profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", target_folder) 
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")
    target_url = 'https://transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.get(target_url)
    if selected_vars:
        for element in selected_vars:
            #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="{}"]'.format(element)).click() # download only selected fields
             #//input[@type='checkbox', @onclick=checkCheck(4)]"
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @title='{}']".format(element)).click()
```

Also, this is my first Stack Overflow post,please let me know if you see any issues with the post, I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you pass to function as `selected_vars`?

Comment: Actually, this is not important. When I visited this site, `OrginAirportID` `OrriginAirportSeqID`  and `OriginCityMarketID` are checked by default. (as well as 3 fields from dest category). You have to add inverse check to your clicking or make sure to deselect everything before your `for` loop.

Comment: Great, thank you! Edit: Apparently, I cannot give you an upvote because I do not have any reputation points yet, sorry.